# Robotic Platforms Similar to the PiBot(Locobot)

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm, manipulator, autonomous-car

I am brain storming platforms to use for a project I am working on. I'm looking for an mobile platform with a manipulator attached. I originally was focusing on the PiBot, but after doing some research the platform might is too short for my project. I am looking for something capable of reaching doorknobs and the tops of tables.

I was wondering if anyone had suggestions for development platforms with the same profile as the locobot (thin and tall on a roomba type base). Or even robots that are used in industry. Let's pretend cost in not an issue for now...

Thanks

Comment: google `khepera robot`

Comment: Will do. Do you know if there is a manip attachment?

Comment: Can your let us know more details of the manipulator, say for example: (1) Torque in KgCm ?, (2) Length of arm segment, degrees of freedom ? (3)  Any claw or hand with how many fingers? (4) Do you need to integrate with software such as OpenGL, TensorFlow? (5) Do you have any preference in hardware/software, eg STM32 linux C++, Rpi linux python,  Jetson Nano JetPack? (6) I know for now cost is not a problem, but do you have a very  estimate, say projects of order similar to PiBot or LoCoBot, Khepera, or many times more to upgrade to industrial applications?